# Relocate NSPersistentStore

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfilemanager, nspersistentstore

I'd like to move the files for my CoreData store of my iOS app from

`../Library/Application Support/MyApp/`

to

`../Documents/Stores/`

Can I just do this with `NSFileManager`, or do I need to use to merge the store from the old location to the new one (there is no data yet at the new location).

Comment: It faster to check this yourself than waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move db file to any location you want. NSFileManager is enough for that.